# Is that possible to update Firestore document child array item only

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to increment or decrement filed `maxQty` and the data structure is added in the below images.

Image with the red mark is the filed and I added another image to understand the data structure

Is there any way to do that?

[image: firestore update document filed array]

[image: firestore update document filed array]

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation regarding [updating array elements](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array):

> If your document contains an array field, you can use `arrayUnion()` and `arrayRemove()` to add and remove elements.

Unfortunately, `arrayUnion()` does not apply to your use-case, as your `businessCard` array contains objects and not strings. There are two options, one would be to read the entire array, increase the `maxQty`, and then write the document back on the server. The second one would be to update the document with the help of a `Map` by manually copying values into it for each of the fields you want to change.

Please also note that the update operation is **not** compatible with the automatic field mapping that occurs with Java POJO objects. You are allowed only to use Map objects.