# How do you change a field in array of maps in firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a Twitter clone and here is my database
[image]

I want to update the **likes** field by increasing its value to 1 when the user clicks on the like button,

Can anyone suggest me how can I update the like field?

Comment: This **[anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60866021/is-that-possible-to-update-firestore-document-child-array-item-only)** will help.

Comment: This structure doesn't look good to me. If your app is successful then this won't scale at all. You're storing all the tweet data in one single document. A doc has a limit of 20k fields, so you're looking for trouble in a way.
In your shoes, I would use a structure like: users(collection) / user (document) / tweets (subcollection) / {tweetId} (document)

Comment: There is no built-in operation to update an item in an array. You'll have to 1) read the document, 2) update the array in your application code, 3) write the entire array back to the database.
This has been covered quite a few times already, so I recommend reading some of these: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+update+item+in+array